# where can i find a good pre-trained model of word2vec that works with js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, word2vec, pre-trained-model

I'm currently using this [pre-trained model](https://rawcdn.githack.com/ml5js/ml5-data-and-models/e77bfb7484bb37babeaba4d1fbf8ea119f14cee6/models/wordvecs/common-english/wordvecs10000.json), but there are a lot of words that are missing from the list.

I am using this for my react.js app, so I need something that works with react, and all the models I found on the internet work for python only.
Where can I find a good pre-trained model that works with react.js?

Comment: Off-site resource requests are generally off topic here. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: This is not the place for such recommendations.